Counting ways to assign red and blue teams, each of $6$ members, from $12$ people standing in a circle, such that no $3$ (or more) reds are adjacent?

If there are $12$ people standing in a circle, 6 are to be placed on the red team and $6$ are to be placed on the blue team. How many ways are there to pick the teams in that way such that are no $3$ (or more) adjacent people on the red team?

The only reasonable way I can find myself doing it is with A LOT of casework, however I feel this is the wrong approach. Help!

Place the 6 red team members around the circle first. Then think of the spaces in between them as bins where you have to place the blue team members such that no two adjacent bins are empty. There is still some casework involved but this greatly simplifies the problem.

The complementary case work of a group of exactly size $~k~$ such that $~k \in {3,4,5,6},~$ allows you to avoid Inclusion-Exclusion, which might be tedious around a circle.  The only gotcha is that when $~k = 3,~$ you might have two separate groups of $~3.~$  Assuming that the people are distinguishable, note that when you fuse $~k~$ people into a group, they can be internally permuted within the group in $~k!~$ ways.

For what it's worth, as indicated by the previous two comments, thoughtful case work is not the wrong approach.

For Enforce's idea, use PIE on the event $A_i = $ bins $i, i+1$ are empty.

@CalvinLin What is PIE?

@copper.hat: Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion

@trueblueanil Thanks :-)

I believe that most of the answers below are incorrect.


For the red teams we could first find out the coefficient of $x^6$ in $(1+x+x^2)^6 =$ 141
[to compute # of ways clumps of $0,1,2$ reds totalling $6$ can be formed]

So the # of circular arrangements $$=\dfrac{141\times 6!6!}6 = 12182400$$


[linear permutations of $6$ red and $6$ blue team members, divided by $6$ to count arrangements upto rotation]
PS:
As @CalvinLin has briefly explained in comments, the figure of $141$ can easily be computed manually, too.
The computation is essentially equivalent to the # of ways a sum of 6 can be obtained by throwing a die with faces $0,1,2$ six times. If you want a bit more detail of how the coefficients have been arrived at, you can look here
Or else, if you aren't comfortable with generating functions, you can use stars and bars with inclusion-exclusion to solve
$x_1+x_2+x_3 +x_4 +x_5 +x_6 = 6, \;0 \leq x_i \leq2\;$ to get
$$\binom{11}5 - \binom61\binom85 +\binom62\binom55 =141$$

Side note: To manually calculate the coefficient of $x^6$ without Cosmic's casework, write it as $[ ( 1 - x^3)/(1-x) ]^6$, which we can expand and ignore higher power terms to get $(1-6x^3+15x^6)(1+6x+21x^2+56x^3+126x^4+252x^5+462x^6)$, hence $462 - 6 \cdot 56 + 15 = 141$.

Excuse my denseness, but  I am missing something here (a few things actually, but one at a time). I assume the $6!6!$ comes from assigning names to the red & blue players. If that is so, then shouldn't the total before multiplying by $6!6!$ be an integer?

@copper.hat: But $141$ is an integer. I have also added a P.S. which explains in more detail what Calvin Lin has written about manually computing $141$

Sorry, I meant if you account for rotations, the result should still be an integer. I am clearly missing something in my reasoning. I need to think a little more.

@copper.hat: $141$ takes into account the relative positions of reds and blues. But since they are all distinct people, to arrange them in a circle, either we fix one person and place the rest , $5!6!$ or compute as $\frac{6!6!}{6}$ to cancel the $6$ rotations.

Is it correct to say that the number of teams (whether you consider rotations equivalent or not) is given by the number of red/blue placements (no names, and either use rotations or not, as long as consistent) multiplied by $6!6!$?

@copper.hat:: We have placed identical blues/reds, and are multiplying bt $6!6!$ because each has a separate identity

I understand that, but it seems to me that as a consequence of what you said that the final result should be divisible by $6!6!$.

I am still grinding on this, but I get $26$ possible unique placements of Rs & Bs with the stated constraints (considering rotations to be equivalent) which is why I am struggling.

I don't think there's a "nice" way to do this problem without using either casework or PIE, but being careful with the casework shouldn't make the calculations too bad. Assuming the players are distinct, we can first "group" the red players into pairs and singlets (since there can't be 3 or more adjacent red players), then "insert" some number of blue players in between each red-player group.
We take cases by the groupings of the red players into pairs and singlets:
Case 1: $2, 2, 2$. Fixing a red player, there are $5!$ ways to arrange the red players around the circle. After ordering, there are $2$ ways to group the red players into pairs, since pairing the fixed player with either its left/right neighbor determines the entire pairing. Now, when inserting the blue players, there are $6!$ ways to order them, and we need to separate them into $3$ groups with at least $1$ blue player in each group. There are $\binom{5}{2}=10$ ways to do this. Hence, the total for this case is $20\cdot 5!\cdot 6!$.
Case 2: $2, 2, 1, 1$. There are once again $5!$ ways to arrange the red players. Going clockwise from the fixed red player, there are $\frac{4!}{2!2!}=6$ ways to arrange the grouping numbers. But $3$ of these number orderings include the fixed player in a pair rather than a singlet, so pairing the fixed player with its left or right neighbor each gives a unique red player grouping. Hence, there are $3\cdot 2+3=9$ ways to group the red players. For the blue player insertion groupings, we use the same logic as before but with $4$ groups to find that there are $6!\cdot \binom{5}{3}$ ways for insertion, for a total of $90\cdot 5!\cdot 6!$.
Case 3: $2, 1, 1, 1, 1$. After ordering the red players, there are $\frac{5!}{4!1!}=5$ ways to arrange the grouping numbers clockwise around the fixed player. But in the $1$ case where the fixed player is in a pair, like before there'll be actually be $2$ possible groupings, so the total will be $6$ red player groupings. Inserting the blue players will have $6!\cdot \binom{5}{4}$ ways, for a total of $30\cdot 5!\cdot 6!$.
Case 4: $1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1$. There's just $1$ way for the red player grouping and $1$ way for the blue player insertion grouping, so this case is just $5!\cdot 6!$.
Hence, the grand total is $141\cdot 5!\cdot 6!=12182400$ ways.
(Note: I've also verified this answer with a computer program in case I screwed up somewhere, but it looks like the answer matches!)

Alternative approach.
The total number of ways of seating the $~12~$ people, where the constraint that you can't have $~3~$ or more adjacent reds is ignored is
$$11!. \tag1 $$
This because you are dealing with a circle, rather than a straight row.

From this initial computation, it is sufficient to deduct all of the ways that the constraint can be violated.
For $~k \in \{4,5,6\},~$ the number of ways of seating the $~12~$ people such that there exists a group of exactly $~k~$ adjacent reds is
$$\binom{6}{k} \times k! \times \binom{6}{2} \times 2! \times (10 - k)! \\= (6!)^2 \times \binom{10 - k}{4}. \tag2 $$
The computation in (2) above is explained as follows:

There are $~\displaystyle \binom{6}{k}~$ ways of choosing which $~k~$ red people will be chosen to form the (fused) unit of $~k~$ people.

There are $~k!~$ ways of internally permuting the $~k~$ people into the fused unit.

Then, since the unit to be fused is to consist of exactly $~k~$ reds, there must be a blue on each of the two ends.  The $~2~$ blues can be chosen in $~\displaystyle \binom{6}{2}~$ ways.

Then, the $~2~$ blues can be permuted in $~2!~$ ways to decide which of the $~2~$ blues is at the start of the fused unit, and which of the $~2~$ blues is at the end of the fused unit.

Since $~k+2~$ people have been fused into $~1~$ unit, the number of units has decreased from $~12~$ units to $~12 - (k+1) = 11 - k~$ units. 
Then, since these units are being permuted around a circle, the number of ways of permuting these units is $~[ ~(11 - k) - 1 ~]!.$



The computation in (2) above also applies, for $~k = 3,~$ with one provision.  In the case of $~k = 3,~$ there is the possibility that the $~6~$ red people will form $~2~$ groups of $~3.~$
With $~k = 3,~$ the computation in (2) above would double-count the situation where there are $~2~$ groups of $~3~$ reds.  This implies that the situation where there are $~2~$ groups of $~3~$ reds would (in effect) be deducted twice.
To compensate for this, the situation where there are $~2~$ groups of $~3~$ reds must be added back.  Consider the following tableau:
                          counted 
                          twice
b r r r b    b r r r b    b r r r b        
b                    b    b       b
b                    b    b r r r b
b r r r b    b r r r b

The computation for the amount to be added back is
$$\binom{6}{3} \times (3!)^2 \times 6! \times \frac{5}{2}. \tag3 $$
This is explained as follows:

In each of the $~3~$ scenarios above, there are $~\displaystyle \binom{6}{3}~$ ways of choosing which $~3~$ of the reds will be seated around the circular table's $~12$-O'clock position.

In each of the $~3~$ scenarios above, there are $~(3!)^2~$ ways of internally permuting each of the $~2~$ groups of $~3~$ reds.

In each of the $~3~$ scenarios above, there are then $~6!~$ ways of permuting the $~6~$ blues.

In only the third scenario above, there are $~3~$ blues on both sides of the groups of reds.  To adjust for the $~3$rd scenario consequently being double-counted, a scalar of $~\dfrac{1}{2}~$ must specifically be assigned to the third scenario.  This accounts for the $~\dfrac{5}{2}~$ factor.



$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$
$$11! - \left[ ~\sum_{k = 3}^6 
(6!)^2 \times \binom{10 - k}{4}
~\right] \\ 
+ \left[ ~\binom{6}{3} \times (3!)^2 \times 6! \times \frac{5}{2} ~\right]$$
$$= 39916800 - 29030400 + 1296000 = 12182400.$$

I get different values to some of the other answers.
The problem can be split into two parts, (i) determine the number of ways the red & blue team can be placed where any two red/blue are considered equivalent and (ii) assign specific red/blue team members to this placement.
Given an answer to (i), we just multiply by $6!6!$ to get an answer, so we focus on the second.
The first part has two possible interpretations, (a) the placements are have specific positions and (b) rotations of a placement are considered equivalent.
Consider (a) first. Name the positions is some direction. Place a blue member at Position 1. Using @trueblueanil's formal approach using $(1+x+x^2)^6$, we can see that there are $141$ possible placements. This means there are $141$ legal placements with a blue member in Position 1. There are exactly the same number of placements with a red member at Position 1, hence the total number of legal placements is $2 \cdot 141 = \bf{282}$. If we consider Part (ii), we get $282 \cdot 6!6! = \bf{146{,}188{,}800}$ placements.
Part (b) seems more difficult to analyse, so I will fall back on case analysis. By rotations I mean that the placement $x_1...x_{12}$ will be considered equivalent to $x_2...x_{12}x_1$, etc, etc.
As an aside, note that any placement starting with a red member is equivalent to a rotated version of a placement starting with a blue member. In particular, we can restrict the search for equivalence classes to those equivalent to a placement starting at Position 1, if it helps.
Note that the expansion in @trueblueanil's answer is very useful for determining equivalence classes. Note that any placement starting with a blue member can be represented as a product $x^{k_1}\cdots x^{k_6}$, where $k_1+\cdots+k_6 = 6$ and $k_i \in \{0,1,2\}$. In particular, we can label any such placement by $k_1...k_6$. Furthermore, by rotating an appropriate number of times, we see that the placement $k_1...k_6$ is equivalent to $k_2...k_6 k_1$ and all rotated versions thereof. In terms of this notation, all such placements contain some $k_i = 0$ except for the placement $111111$.
In the following we assume that $k_1=0$ when counting the equivalence classes of placements other than $111111$.
We base the case analysis on the number of pairs of red members. Case 2 is the most tedious and is dealt with last.
Case 0: Zero RR pairs: It is straightforward to see that there is just one equivalence class $111111$.
Case 1: One RR pair: We can assume the labeling starts with $0$ and we wish to place a $2$ in one of the remaining places so there are $5$ distinct equivalence classes $011112,...,021111$.
Case 3: Three RR pairs: There are no $1$s, so assume the labeling starts with $0$. Since rotated placements are equivalent, we can assume that the placement ends with $2$. This leaves $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ possibilities to consider, a little grind shows that these are (1) $000222$, (2) $002022, 022002$, (3) $002202, 020022$ and (4) $020202$. The groupings (2) & (3) are rotationally equivalent, hence there are $4$ distinct equivalence classes.
Finally, Case 2: Two RR pairs, this is very tedious.
If the sequence starts with $00$ then each legal selection of the remaining 4 places corresponds to a distinct equivalence class, hence there are $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ of these.
If the sequence starts with $010$ then each legal selection of the remaining 3 places corresponds to a distinct equivalence class consisting of the arrangements of $122$, hence they are $010122, 010212, 010221$. Note that the equivalent classes of these include $012201, 021201, 022101$ respectively. That is, there are three new equivalence classes.
If the sequence starts with $011$ then each legal selection of the remaining 3 places corresponds to a distinct equivalence class consisting of the arrangements of $022$, hence they are $011022, 011202, 011220$. Note that the equivalent classes of these include
$022011, 020112$, but the last is equivalent to $001122$ which has already been counted. Hence there are two new equivalence classes.
If the sequence starts with $012$ then each legal selection of the remaining 3 places corresponds to a distinct equivalence class consisting of the arrangements of $012$. There are $3!=6$ candidates, ending in $012, 021,101,120,210,210$, a quick check shows that the last 3 have already been accounted for (by $001212, 010122, 0011221$) hence there are three new equivalence classes.
If the sequence starts with $020$, then the remaining places take an arrangement of $112$. If the fourth place is a $1$ then this would correspond to an already counted equivalence class. Hence this just adds a single equivalence class corresponding to $020211$.
If the sequence starts with $021$, then the remaining places take one of the $3!=6$ candidate arrangement of $012$. Any candidate ending in $0$, $10$ or $20$ has already been counted. The two remaining candidates are $021012, 021021$, and the first is equivalent to $012021$ which has already been counted. Hence this adds one more equivalent class.
Hence there are total of $1+5+4+6+3+2+3+1+1=26$ distinct equivalence classes.
Hence for Part (b), we have (i) $\bf{26}$ possible placements if any two red/blue are considered equivalent and (ii) $26 \cdot 6! 6! = \bf{13{,}478{,}400}$ if we assign specific red/blue team members.
Addendum: As a quick check (well, it takes 5-10 mins. to run) I used the following Python script. The output was
total=479001600 count=146188800 len(unique)=26

# https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5003867/counting-ways-to-assign-red-and-blue-teams-each-of-6-members-from-12-peopl
# python mse_prob2_3.py
# 6 red 6 blue no more than two red together in a circle.

import itertools

# Track unique placements, this is the string doubled for quick lookup.
unique = []

# x ranges of all placements, so check if x or a rotated version has already
# been encountered.
# When a new placement is found, create the corresponding string s and save
# a copy of s+s. This makes it easy to check rotations.
def valid(x):
    l = len(x)
    for i in range(l):
        if x[i][0] == 'R' and x[(i+1) % l][0] == 'R' and x[(i+2) % l][0] == 'R':
            return False
    s = "".join(map(lambda e: e[0], x))
    for u in unique:
        if s in u:
            return True
    unique.append(s + s)
    print(f"valid: len(unique)={len(unique)}")
    return True

reds = [f"R{i}" for i in range(1, 7)]
blues = [f"B{i}" for i in range(1, 7)]
allTeams = reds + blues

count = 0
total = 0
for item in itertools.permutations(allTeams):
    total += 1
    if valid(item):
        count += 1
    if total % 10000000 == 0:
        # 479001600 == 12!
        print(f" progress {total/479001600}")

print(f"total={total} count={count} len(unique)={len(unique)}")

